# Can't figure why i get ORA-24344: success with compilation error

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, oracle-apex

i'm new in pl sql and this is the first package i'm creating for a school project. I'm using oracle apex, the browser version to compile this code and i get the error mentioned above, Unfortunately i don't know how to debug this. I tried running each procedure and function on it's own to see if they work and i always got "PLS-00103: encountered the symbol "end-of-file."

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE package_farmacie AS
procedure stergere_angajat(nr_angajat angajati_f.ID%type);
procedure stergere;
function salariu_mediu return number;
procedure afisare;
numar_angajati_stersi integer;
sal_mediu number;
end;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY package_farmacie AS
procedure produse;
procedure salariu_angajat;
procedure salariu_angajat is
    cursor c1 is select * from angajati_f where salariu <(select avg(salariu) from angajati_f) order by salariu;
    cursor c2 is select * from angajati_f where salariu >(select avg(salariu) from anagajati_f) order by salariu;
begin
dbms_output.put_line(‘Angajati cu salariu mai mic decat media’);
for i in c1 loop
dbms_output.put_line(i.ID||’ ‘||i.prenume||i.salariu);
exit when c1%notfound;
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(‘Angajati cu salariu peste medie’);
for i in c2 loop
dbms_output.put_line(i.ID||’ ‘||i.prenume||i.salariu);
end loop;
end;


procedure stergere is
numar_angajati_stersi angajati_f.ID%type;
    begin
            select count(ID)
        into numar_angajati_stersi
        from sefi_schimb;
        delete from sefi_schimb;
        dbms_output.put_line('Au fost stersi '|| numar_angajati_stersi ||' angajati!');
    end;


function salariu_mediu return number is
    sal_mediu angajati_f.salariu%type;
    begin
       select avg(salariu)
       into sal_mediu
       from angajati_f;
       dbms_output.put_line('Salariul mediu este: '||sal_mediu);
       return sal_mediu;
       salariu_angajat();
    end;


function afisare_angajati return nume is
cursor afisare is SELECT nume FROM angajati_f;
nume_angajat angajati_f.nume%type;
begin 
open afisare;
loop
fetch afisare into nume_angajat;
if afisare%NOTFOUND then 
exit;
end if;
Dbms_output.put_line(‘Angajati gasiti:’||nume_angajat);
end loop;
close afisare;
end;


procedure stergere_angajat(nr_angajat angajati_f.ID%type) is
id_angajat angajati_f.ID%type;
    begin
            select ID
        into id_angajat
        from angajati_f
            where ID = nr_angajat;
            delete from angajati_f
            where ID = nr_angajat;
        dbms_output.put_line('Stergere cu succes!');
dbms_output.put_line('A(u)fost sters( e) '|| SQL%ROWCOUNT ||' rand(uri)!');
    exception
        when no_data_found then
           dbms_output.put_line('Id-ul angajatului nu exista!');
angajati := afisare_angajati();
dbms_output.put_line(angajati); 
    end;


procedure produse is
cursor c_produse (cod_produse_in IN varchar2)
is 
    select denumire
    from produse_f
    where cod = cod_produse_in;
prod_denumire produse_f.denumire%type;
begin
      dbms_output.put_line('Lista produselor in functie de cod: '||cod_produse_in);
open c_produse(cod_produse_in);
loop 
    fetch c_produse
          into prod_denumire;
          if (c_produse%notfound = true) then
                 close c_produse;
             return; 
          end if;
  dbms_output.put_line(prod_denumire);
end loop;     
end;      


procedure afisare is
    begin 
        produse();
    end;
end;
```

i've checked for typos in my table & columns names and they are correctly written is it the syntax or the whole code is a mess?

Comment: I'm not familiar with using Apex to create packages. Does it require some delimiter between the package and package body statements? A lot of tools do.

Comment: i did not execute them together, i just put them here in case it helps

Comment: Where exactly did you run this code?

Comment: That error message generally means you have submitted something to the database that hasn’t been ended properly. Here, you need to be submitting the package specification and the package body separately. I don’t use the APEX SQL gui to run SQL but I imagine you want to stick `/` after each of the blocks on a separate line to submit them. Alternatively, you want to just submit the package spec code, then just submit the package body code.

Comment: that's how i submit it, first the spec code then the body. I get the error only when executing the body

Comment: The compilation errors will be listed in the `user_errors` view. If your Apex environment doesn't have any tools to help development, you can just query `user_errors`.

Comment: Thank you so much @WilliamRobertson, with this i solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

When I copy/paste from your question, you are using the quotes `‘’` when you should be using single straight quotes `'`. Make sure that whatever user interface you are using to create your package is not replacing single straight quotes `'` with angled quotes.

Also:

- ```sql
  function afisare_angajati return nume
  ```

  Should return a data type rather than a column identifier; such as:

  ```sql
  function afisare_angajati return angajati_f.nume%TYPE
  ```
- ```sql
  angajati := afisare_angajati();
  ```

  The `angajati` variable is not declared; you could just combine the that line with the next to not use an intermediate variable:

  ```sql
  dbms_output.put_line(afisare_angajati());
  ```
- Also `cod_produse_in` is not declared outside the cursor, even though you try to use it as a PL/SQL variable outside the cursor.

*(Note: I have only looked for syntax errors and have not tried to understand what the code does.)*

Comment: thanks, i corrected my code still get same error